# Culture is not supported (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, cultureinfo, regioninfo

Within a WPF App (.NET Framework 4.5.2) I use an IValueConverter to get the RegionInfo from a 2 letter region code:

```cs
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {

 if (value != null) { // 
  // we use local list of regions (due to perfomance issue : new RegionInfo() )
  //
  var key = value.ToString();
  if (regionsName.ContainsKey(key)) return regionsName[key];

  regionsName.Add(key, new RegionInfo(value.ToString()).DisplayName);
  return regionsName[key];
 }

 return null;
}
```

This works well almost everywhere. Now one customer gets an exception:

> TypeString: System.ArgumentException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Message   : Culture
>   name "MU" is not supported. Parametername: name

When I locally call the Convert-Method with value="MU" I get 'Mauritius' as corresponding DisplayName (from RegionInfo). So "MU" seems to be a valid RegionCode.

So why is this code unknown on the clients machine? And how can I fix this?

Comment: This should give you more clues and looks like you are getting similar error. https://winterdom.com/2017/07/26/invalidculture

Comment: Which .NET version and Windows OS does your customer use?

Comment: Its a Windows 7 PC. .NET Framework 4.5.2 must be installed (otherwise out App woulnd't work). I just checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c?redirectedfrom=MSDN and it look like the en-MU / fr-MU ist first supported in Windows 10. Could this be the cause?

Comment: Yes, it can be a root cause, because it's release 10 culture, Win 7 supports only release 7. You can get the list of supported cultures by `Cultureinfo.GetCultures` method call and allow user to select only the supported ones

Comment: OK. have to try this. Bad thing about this: It's related to a centralized customer database wher eonly thw twoletterisocode is stored. And hving a customer in mauritius is absolutely valid. The Win7 user will never be able to create such a custoemr (since this countrycode is not available in customer creation dialog either). But Wi10 user is. and Win7 must be able to see all customers. But thank you for this.